# How to make a Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile

I need a **Dockerfile** to run my **Python script**. The script uses **Selenium**, so I need to load a driver for it to work. An ordinary .exe file - driver is not suitable, so according to the advice of the administrators of the hosting where the script is located I need to create a Dockerfile for the script to work properly.

The main problem is that I simply can not run my script, because I do not understand how to load the required driver on the server.

**This is a sample code of what should be in the Dockerfile.**

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -O $HOME/geckodriver.tar.gz https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.23.0/geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar xf $HOME/geckodriver.tar.gz -C $HOME
RUN cp $HOME/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
RUN rm -f $HOME/geckodriver $HOME/geckodriver.tar.gz
```

**This is the code used in the Python script**

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x935')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(f"https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/{id}/feedbacks?imtId={imt_id}")
time.sleep(5)
big_stat = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="rating-product__numb")
```

I can redo this snippet of code to make it work on Firefox, if necessary.

**This is what the directories of the hosting where all the files are located look like**
[The directories of the hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7ypw.png)

Comment: When running on Windows 10 using an .exe file, everything works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting Selenium to work with Python using a Dockerfile, here's an existing [SeleniumBase Dockerfile](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/Dockerfile).

For instructions on using it, [see the README](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/integrations/docker/ReadMe.md).

For building, it's basically this:

Non Apple M1 Mac:

```bash
docker build -t seleniumbase .
```

If running on an Apple M1 Mac, use this instead:

```bash
docker build --platform linux/amd64 seleniumbase .
```

Before building the Dockerfile, you'll need to clone [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase).

Here's what the Dockerfile currently looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

#=======================================
# Install Python and Basic Python Tools
#=======================================
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false -o Acquire::Check-Date=false update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev python-distribute
RUN alias python=python3
RUN echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.bashrc

#=================================
# Install Bash Command Line Tools
#=================================
RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    wget \
    curl \
    libxi6 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    vim \
    xvfb \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#================
# Install Chrome
#================
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#=================
# Install Firefox
#=================
RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install \
     $(apt-cache depends firefox | grep Depends | sed "s/.*ends:\ //" | tr '\n' ' ') \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && cd /tmp \
  && wget --no-check-certificate -O firefox-esr.tar.bz2 \
    'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-esr-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US' \
  && tar -xjf firefox-esr.tar.bz2 -C /opt/ \
  && ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox \
  && rm -f /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2

#===========================
# Configure Virtual Display
#===========================
RUN set -e
RUN echo "Starting X virtual framebuffer (Xvfb) in background..."
RUN Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
RUN export DISPLAY=:99
RUN exec "$@"

#=======================
# Update Python Version
#=======================
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install python3.8
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s python3.8 /usr/bin/python3

#=============================================
# Allow Special Characters in Python Programs
#=============================================
RUN export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
RUN echo "export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8" >> ~/.bashrc

#=====================
# Set up SeleniumBase
#=====================
COPY sbase /SeleniumBase/sbase/
COPY seleniumbase /SeleniumBase/seleniumbase/
COPY examples /SeleniumBase/examples/
COPY integrations /SeleniumBase/integrations/
COPY requirements.txt /SeleniumBase/requirements.txt
COPY setup.py /SeleniumBase/setup.py
RUN find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
RUN find . -name __pycache__ -delete
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools-scm
RUN cd /SeleniumBase && ls && pip3 install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
RUN cd /SeleniumBase && pip3 install .

#=====================
# Download WebDrivers
#=====================
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN chmod +x geckodriver
RUN mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN chmod +x chromedriver
RUN mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/

#==========================================
# Create entrypoint and grab example tests
#==========================================
COPY integrations/docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY integrations/docker/run_docker_test_in_firefox.sh /
COPY integrations/docker/run_docker_test_in_chrome.sh /
RUN chmod +x *.sh
COPY integrations/docker/docker_config.cfg /SeleniumBase/examples/
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Actually I need to copy your code, paste it into a Dockerfile and run it? I just don't know how it works at all...

Comment: And as far as I understand it will have to be done once?

Comment: You only have to build it once. Then your environment is set. This Dockerfile is specific to a cloned copy of SeleniumBase. Then you can run as much Python Selenium automation as you need. (SeleniumBase will simplify that.)

Comment: Could you please explain to me in detail how and what to do? Right now all I understand is that I need to install seleniumbase using Docker ```docker build -t seleniumbase``` and run the Dockerfile with the contents FROM ubuntu:18.04... etc.

Comment: Step 1: Clone SeleniumBase from GitHub.
Step 2: Run ``docker build -t seleniumbase .`` from the top-level SeleniumBase folder.
Step 3: Run ``docker run seleniumbase ./run_docker_test_in_chrome.sh`` to make sure everything is working.

Comment: And what do I need to change in my python script code to make it work correctly with the right driver?

Comment: SeleniumBase handles the drivers automatically. Easy-to-use format. See [basic_test.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/basic_test.py) for an example. Lots of other examples in the [examples/](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/tree/master/examples) folder.